# Symfony onKernelException listener

Tags: php, symfony, exception, listener

I'm trying to set up a listener that notifies me (via email for example) when an error is thrown. I have set up an `ExceptionListener` that works fine when I throw an error 500 like such:

```
throw new \Exception( 'Something went wrong!', 500 );
```

However on other cases, for example when I purposefully call a non-existant class like that:

```
$error = new NotExistantClass;
```

I don't get anything from my listener in this case, be it in prod or dev mode. Also in prod mode, I get a white page and not my error 500 page.

**Is it possible to avoid this behavior? (ie. get a fatal error that fails into an error 500 page and get my listener to notify me)**

Here is the actual listener: (I don't put the `services.yml` since the listener seems to work efficiently)

```
public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
{
    $exception = $event->getException();
    $flatException = FlattenException::create( $exception );
    $code = $flatException->getStatusCode();
    //$code = $exception->getCode();
    //die( var_dump( $code ) );
    if ( $code == 500 ) {
        // notifies me
    }
}
```

Additionally, if anyone can enlighten on the use of the FlattenException and the difference between the Status Code and the Code, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 2):

There's a [built-in solution for emailing exceptions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/monolog_email.html).

Regarding your listener not working in some cases. Fatal errors don't leave Symfony a chance to handle them in any way. A fatal error is using a non-existent class or calling a non-existent method. These types of errors are programming errors and can't be handled by Symfony basically because PHP just dies there.

Comment: Aw, bummer. But it does get logged with stack trace, right? How is that possible if PHP just dies?

Comment: I believe it is inside `Symfony\Component\Debug` through the `handleFatal` function. (And this is not something I want to override randomly of course)